# imbalance data in RevoScaleR’s (SQL 2016)

Tags: r

How do you deal with imbalance data in RevoScaleR (SQL 2016)?

I tried to use params with the ration of my training dataset and still have the same issue.

Comment: share your code here

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].